# Is it possible to move documents in Skydrive?

Tags: office-365, onedrive

It seems like pretty basic functionality and I think I must be missing something, but is there a way to move documents within the skydrive web app?  It seems like this feature was lost in the recent overhaul of Skydrive.

Answer (score 3):

1. Mark the little checkbox in the upper right-hand corner of the tile that represents the document in your SkyDrive.
2. Click on **Manage** in the bar on the top, then click on **Move to**.

   [image]
3. You'll now be given the option to select the target location for your file.

   [image]

Alternatively, SkyDrive also supports Drag & Drop to achieve move operations:

[image]